# How to share a DNN module across sites?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am very new to DNN. I have a module on my page - http://localhost:10000/us. I want to have that module on all the other sites mentioned below: http://localhost:10000/demo
http://localhost:10000/uk
http://localhost:10000/de

I tried 'IsShareable' checkbox under Advanced Settings of the module settings.  But that didn't help.

I expect the module to be added to my other sites too.

Answer (score 0):

To share modules across different portals you need to use the "Portal Groups" feature. There is no interface for that in the Platform, only in the commercial product (Evoq), nevertheless it works (as the API is there).

But there are community contributions for this, e.g. [Connect.Sitegroups](https://github.com/SCullman/Connect.Sitegroups)

Comment: How do I use that?

Comment: It is more or less self-explaining, but to get the basic idea you could read [this blog article](http://www.bitboxx.net/Blog/Post/191/Single-Sign-on-SSO-and-Modulesharing-in-DotNetNuke-CE-06-01-00-and-above#/) - here it is done without a UI, but directly in the database.

Comment: I went through the article but to be honest it didn't help. I am very new to DNN. It would be great if you elaborate on how exactly I add a module on all the portals.

Comment: There are step-by-step instructions in Torsten's blog article mentioned above. There is no mechanism that shares the module automatically, you have to add it to a page as you do with adding an existing module, with the only difference is that the module is not from another page in the same portal but from another page in another portal.

Comment: Ah, ok, I forgot to mention that all the portals have to be within the same DNN installation.